# Testcafe - Select an element that contains 'text' or 'text'

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, selector, testcafe

I am trying to get an element that contains a text in English **OR** a text in French. However, it only take the first text into account in ('text in French'||'text in English').
How can I select the element in both language?

MailtHelper:

```
async getEmail(filterEmail: string, filterSubject: string): Promise<string> {
        const filtered = json.filter(item => item['to_email'] === filterEmail && item['subject'] && item['subject'].includes(filterSubject));
        if (filtered.length > 0) {
            const emailLink = await this.getEmail(filtered[0].html_path);
            result = htmlDecoderHelper.decodeHTMLEntities(emailLink);
        } else {
            console.log("No email found");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Test

```
test
('forgotPassword', 
 async t => {
  await t
    .click (ResetPasswordPage.mainPageButton);

    const emailLink = await MailHelper.getMailEmail('email', ('text in French'||'text in English'));
    console.log('resetPasswordEmail: ', emailLink);

  await t.navigateTo(emailLink)
    .expect(ResetPasswordPage.newPasswordCriterias.exists).ok()
  });
```

I tried all the variants for `const emailLink = await MailHelper.getMailEmail('email', ('text in French'||'text in English'));`

Only the first part is taken into account and the test fails when I change the language to EN.

Answer (score 1):

`MailHelper.getMailEmail('email', ('text in French'||'text in English'))` is just wrong

`('text in French'||'text in English')`

the `||` is a **or** operator which returns the first argument if the first argument is True or the second argument, in this case a string is always True unless the string is empty

```
> 'first' || "second"
> 'first'
```

```
> '' || "second"
> 'second'
```

You need to change your function and pass a list of strings:

`MailHelper.getMailEmail('email', ['text in French', 'text in English'])`

```
async getEmail(filterEmail: string, filterSubjects: string[]): Promise<string> {
    for (subject in filterSubjects){
         ... your code
    }
    ...
}
```